# Laravel voyager migration issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

I am working on windows and WAMP. I installed Laravel 5.4 within cmd and that was successful. After that I follow laravel voyager installation process and that was successful too.

Afterwards I checked `/migrations/` folder and there are many tables for migration, for laravel itself and for voyager, but when I type `php artisan migrate` in cmd it migrate only "users" table, it ignored other tables so voyager is not working and showing errors that tables are missing.

I searched internet but could not find this type of issue.

I'm using mysql

Comment: I remember reading somehwere that voyager doesnt create a new table with a new model,so it might be that voyager is not that solid.It was on a yt video so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: It auto-created tables in datatables folder but when in try to migrate it ignores them

Comment: Maybe  open an issue on github

Comment: what is the result of `php artisan migrate:status` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the Voyager documentation it says the following:

Before installing Voyager make sure you have installed one of the following versions of Laravel:

- Laravel 6
- Laravel 7
- Laravel 8

Additionally Voyager requires you to use PHP 7.3 or newer.

Apparently with Laravel 5.4 it will not work .
To use Voyager on Laravel 5.x, you need to use version 1.3 of Laravel Voyager: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/tree/1.3

Remembering that it is not necessary to use the migrate command for Voyager to work.

The steps are:

```
composer require tcg/voyager
```

Next step you must create your database and insert your credentials in the .env file

You can choose to install Voyager without dummy data or with dummy data. For an installation without a dummy data, run the command:

```
php artisan voyager:install
```

For a dummy data installation:

```
php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy
```

You will need to access the url http://localhost:8000/ admin to access the voyager, if you installed with dummy data, you will have a super user created, with the following credentials:

```
email: admin@admin.com
password: password
```

If you have not created any dummy users, you can set an existing user in your database as admin by running the command:

```
php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com
```

Or you can create a new admin user, using the command:

```
php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create
```